# Windows ListView with CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListView Control in WindowsForm and also this Listivew has a checkBox  I Just want one thing that when userClick on CheckBox I want this Event
I used  ItemCheck and ItemChecked Event but these event is firing every time even when Firstime my form is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listview control fires itemcheck and itemchecked (and some other) events sometimes at initialization, provided "by design" by Microsoft at no extra charge. You can set a flag (boolean variable) to tell whether the form has completed the loading process, and abort the handler if not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the top of your event handler:

```
if (!this.Visible) return;
```

Comment: If you can't understand what the line does, consider finding another career.  (`this` is your form)